# Use for /f tokens and compare-op or any method for live Web Dictionary with 26 words in File (batch script)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to run an online dictionary to translate words from a text file "polish_words.txt" using a batch script. This should open new few new tabs, 5 in this case but it opens 4 and 1 empty. The order is random (1,3,4,2,5) or (Em,4,1,3,5) instead of (1,2,3,4,5). Which is also a problem that it doesn't execute in sequence. I want the script to be correct and do what I expect from it, which is to open all the words.

I currently have two variables combined. I'm curious if it is possible to add a third variable to add `&end"` at the end. This combination doesn't work `%przegladarka%%%A%third%`.

The main problem is that it should correctly opens tabs with words in Polish. So if i execute 10, it should open 10 tabs, not 6.

**polish_words.txt**

```
łódka dwa trzy cztery piec
```

**english_dictionary_script.bat**

```
@echo off
REM remember set "Encoding" to "ANSI" for "polish_words.txt"
@chcp 1250

SET przegladarka=start /d "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox" firefox.exe "https://www.diki.pl/slownik-angielskiego?q=

FOR /f "tokens=1-26 usebackq delims= " %%A in ("polish_words.txt") DO (
IF [%%A] NEQ [] %przegladarka%%%A&end"
IF [%%B] NEQ [] %przegladarka%%%B&end"
IF [%%C] NEQ [] %przegladarka%%%C&end"
IF [%%D] NEQ [] %przegladarka%%%D&end"
IF [%%E] NEQ [] %przegladarka%%%E&end"
IF [%%F] NEQ [] %przegladarka%%%F"
IF [%%G] NEQ [] %przegladarka%%%G"
IF [%%H] NEQ [] %przegladarka%%%H"
IF [%%I] NEQ [] %przegladarka%%%I"
IF [%%J] NEQ [] %przegladarka%%%J"
IF [%%K] NEQ [] %przegladarka%%%K
IF [%%L] NEQ [] %przegladarka%%%L
IF [%%M] NEQ [] %przegladarka%%%M
IF [%%N] NEQ [] %przegladarka%%%N
IF [%%O] NEQ [] %przegladarka%%%O
IF [%%P] NEQ [] %przegladarka%%%P
IF [%%Q] NEQ [] %przegladarka%%%Q
IF [%%R] NEQ [] %przegladarka%%%R
IF [%%S] NEQ [] %przegladarka%%%S
IF [%%T] NEQ [] %przegladarka%%%T
IF [%%U] NEQ [] %przegladarka%%%U
IF [%%V] NEQ [] %przegladarka%%%V
IF [%%W] NEQ [] %przegladarka%%%W
IF [%%X] NEQ [] %przegladarka%%%X
IF [%%Y] NEQ [] %przegladarka%%%Y
IF [%%Z] NEQ [] %przegladarka%%%Z
)
pause
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
```

Comment: Why not use ```Set "przegladarka=%ProgramFiles%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"```, ```Set "adres=https://www.diki.pl/slownik-angielskiego?q="```, and ```Set "koncowka=^&end"```. Then you should be able to use, for example, ```Start "" "%przegladarka%" "https://www.diki.pl/slownik-angielskiego?q=%%A%koncowka%"```. As for the order, how about using ```%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 2 /NoBreak 1>NUL``` between each `start`ed command. I would also advise that you change all ```IF [%%A] NEQ []``` to ```If Not "%%A" == ""```. BTW, your last line is not a valid command, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I didn't try to do anything on the last line. I wrote the alphabet to know how many words I can store in a text file and refer to them. Just to let me know that I have 26 variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

REM remember set "Encoding" to "ANSI" for "polish_words.txt"
@chcp 1250
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%e IN ("polish_words.txt") DO FOR %%o ON (%%e) start "%%o" /d "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox" firefox.exe "https://www.diki.pl/slownik-angielskiego?q=%%o&end"&timeout /t 1 >nul

GOTO :EOF
```

**[untested]**

Batch routines should usually have `setlocal` so that the original environment is restored when the batch ends and variables are not endlessly accumulated, which can lead to problems with later batches in the same `cmd` session.

The first `for` grabs the line from the file and assigns it in its entirety (`delims=`) to `%%e`. The second `for` iterates ove the values in `%%e`, assigning each in turn to `%%o`.

The first quoted string in a `start` command becomes the window title, so it's my habit to assign that to some identifying string. It can be an empty string if you prefer.

Why `start /d...` and not `start "title" "fullpathname to executable\executablename"...` idk - both will probably work.

I've added a timeout to attempt to cater for the sequence problem which is probably caused by the various instances of firefox experiencing different response times. May need to increase the `1`...idk

By using `FOR %%o ON (%*) start...` you could use simply

```
thisbatch I know no Polish
```

to open the pages "I" "know" "no" and "Polish" - which may save establishing/editing the file

---- revision

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

REM remember set "Encoding" to "ANSI" for "polish_words.txt"
chcp 1250

fOR /f "delims=" %%e IN ('type "q76956389.txt"') DO FOR %%o iN (%%e) do start "%%o" /d "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox" firefox.exe "https://www.diki.pl/slownik-angielskiego?q=%%o&end"&timeout /t 1 >nul

FOR %%o iN (%*) DO start "%%o" /d "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox" firefox.exe "https://www.diki.pl/slownik-angielskiego?q=%%o&end"&timeout /t 1 >NUL
)

GOTO :EOF
```

The first (nested) `for` reads the file as it is `type`d. I used a Unicode file here as the first character of the first word isn't savable in an ANSI file. "It worked for me".

The second `for` interprets the command line with the word-list cut-and-pasted from OP's post.

I used `q76956389.txt` instead of `polish_words.txt` as I keep all of my answers with support data on my machine. This is SO question 76956389.

The problems with the original post were `for ... ON` should have been `for ... IN`  and the `do` was missing before the `start`.

The `for /f` option `usebackqdelims=` is perfectly valid. The individual options `usebackq` and `delims=` can have a space between them if you prefer - it is optional (and less typing). `delims=` with no characters before the `"` means "no delimiters - deliver the entire line as a string". The `usebackq` is required as the filename is quoted to allow separators like spaces in the full pathname of the file, hence the alternative quote-set is required (see `for /?` from the prompt for documentation).

UNFORTUNATELY, `for /f` doesn't appear to like unicode files, so the `type` version appears to be required.

There really should be no practical limit to the number of words supplied, either on the command-line or in the file. about 4000 characters would be the logical limit - but I haven't tested it that much.

Comment: Your [untested] script doesn't work, it doesn't execute at all, unfortunately I don't know why but it doesn't do anything. You should make corrections. DOESN'T WORK. I have no idea.

Comment: I don't know if `tokens` option wasn't needed for proper code execution. Previously script informed what is the maximum number of elements in the file. So I don't know if you mean to say that the number of elements is unlimited. Here is the specification of [loop command](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html). And why did you save together `usebackq` and `delims` as `usebackqdelims=`? This is probably not the correct file save, but even after correcting, the script doesn't work either. There may be a syntax error here. But I'm not that good at writing scripts to make the appropriate correction.

Comment: So i don't know what is wrong.